# Getting files on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating json files `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "test"," {Hour}.json ";` I can see the files on the device in Xcode.. once I return only one with this `Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "test",".json")` then I can read its content.

However once I need to return all files from the directory and list the path to them in my application

```
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "test");
```

The result is empty

```
this is the path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/02A91048-0016-4E20-A8A6-EB2A89649F1F/Library
```

which is correct an I see the files the physical. Where am I doing mistake?

I have also tried this

```
var test = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory);
```

but I am getting unauthorized exception

Comment: What are the actual names of the files?

Comment: each different all stored in folder test  with .json..names of the files should be {Hour}.json

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for files in the **test** subfoloder

the signature of `EnumerateFiles` is

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles (string path, string searchPattern);
```

so you want to do this

```
var path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory,"test");
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.json");
```